# Split large CSV and Remove Column

Tags: python, csv

I am using this code to split a large CSV file. This works flawlessly however I am wondering how I would adjust to remove a column from the output files? I am splitting my csv based on the values in column 2 and want only column 1 returned.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import binascii
import csv
import os.path
import sys
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
from tkinter.simpledialog import askinteger

def split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, keyfunc):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    csv_writers = {}
    for row in csv_reader:
        k = keyfunc(row)
        if k not in csv_writers:
            csv_writers[k] = csv.writer(open(os.path.join(dst_dir, k),
                                             mode='w', newline=''))
        csv_writers[k].writerow(row)

def get_args_from_cli():
    input_filename = sys.argv[1]
    column = int(sys.argv[2])
    dst_dir = sys.argv[3]
    return (input_filename, column, dst_dir)

def get_args_from_gui():
    input_filename = askopenfilename(
        filetypes=(('CSV', '.csv'),),
        title='Select CSV Input File')
    column = askinteger('Choose Table Column', 'Table column')
    dst_dir = askdirectory(title='Select Destination Directory')
    return (input_filename, column, dst_dir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        input_filename, column, dst_dir = get_args_from_gui()
    elif len(sys.argv) == 4:
        input_filename, column, dst_dir = get_args_from_cli()
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid number of arguments")
    with open(input_filename, mode='r', newline='') as f:
        split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, lambda r: r[column-1]+'.csv')
        # if the column has funky values resulting in invalid filenames
        # replace the line from above with:
        # split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, lambda r: binascii.b2a_hex(r[column-1].encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')+'.csv')
```

Here is an example of the begining CSV

```
"<option value="""">Choose Year</option>",ParentID
"<option value=""Civic1990"">1990</option>",Civic
"<option value=""CRX1990"">1990</option>",CRX
"<option value=""Prelude1990"">1990</option>",Prelude
"<option value=""Accord1990"">1990</option>",Accord
"<option value=""Prelude1991"">1991</option>",Prelude
"<option value=""Civic1991"">1991</option>",Civic
"<option value=""CRX1991"">1991</option>",CRX
"<option value=""Accord1991"">1991</option>",Accord
"<option value=""Prelude1992"">1992</option>",Prelude
"<option value=""Civic1992"">1992</option>",Civic
"<option value=""Accord1992"">1992</option>",Accord
"<option value=""Prelude1993"">1993</option>",Prelude
"<option value=""Civic1993"">1993</option>",Civic
"<option value=""CivicdelSol1993"">1993</option>",CivicdelSol
"<option value=""Accord1993"">1993</option>",Accord
"<option value=""Passport1994"">1994</option>",Passport
```

And when finished I would like the outcome to look like:

```
<option value="">Choose Year</option>
<option value="Civic1990">1990</option>
<option value="Civic1991">1991</option>
<option value="Civic1992">1992</option>
<option value="Civic1993">1993</option>
<option value="Civic1994">1994</option>
<option value="Civic1995">1995</option>
<option value="Civic1996">1996</option>
<option value="Civic1997">1997</option>
<option value="Civic1998">1998</option>


<option value="">Choose Year</option>
<option value="Accord1990">1990</option>
<option value="Accord1991">1991</option>
<option value="Accord1992">1992</option>
<option value="Accord1993">1993</option>
<option value="Accord1994">1994</option>
<option value="Accord1995">1995</option>
<option value="Accord1996">1996</option>
<option value="Accord1997">1997</option>
<option value="Accord1998">1998</option>
```

etc... 
 so each year and option value for the specific model are in their own csv or txt files.

Comment: can you post a sample of your csv file? and an expected output sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows are just lists of Python strings, so try:

```
csv_writers[k].writerow(row[0:1])
```

This will only write the first column.

**Second question:**

In Python you can use `str.replace(substr, new_substr)`.

Here we are talking potentially a list of strings (I know there is only one string in the list in this scenario), so list comprehension come in handy.

```
csv_writers[k].writerow([v.replace('""', '"') for v in row[0:1]])
```

This generates a new list with all strings having replaced `""` with `"`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, is there a way to replace text such as "" with "?

Comment: Do you mean empty strings (`""`) with a question mark (`"?"`)?

Comment: No the double quote with a single quote ( " ") with ( " )

Comment: I will update my answer, tell me if I misunderstand :-)

Comment: Thank you. Yes you understand correctly. However it is not working :/

Comment: When you write CSV files then any text containing `"` is escaped by making it a double `""`. So the problem here is the CSV writer. If you read it again with CSV reader, then it will be translated back into a single `"`. You can write to a normal file instead.

Comment: I believe that is my issue I am trying to write to .txt file. which is working fine aside from the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the pandas functions: [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

the rest is [here](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dropping_column_and_rows.ht)

```
df.drop('column_name', axis=1)
```